Асинхронный запуск и управление процессом в отдельном терминале с получением кода возврата
Мне надо портировать часть кода, написанного для Windows, под Linux, сохранив поведение.
В Windows можно из программы запустить отдельный процесс, получить его хэндл и по этому хэндлу ждать завершения процесса и получить его код возврата. Примерно так:
CreateProcessA(NULL, "YourCommandLine", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitCode);

Эти действия происходят асинхронно, не блокируя вызывающий поток. И, что важно, при этом вывод запущенного исполняемого файла не будет перенаправлен в консоль основного процесса. Т.е. если запускается консольное приложение, то для него будет запущена отдельная консоль, в которую и пойдет вывод.
Как добиться аналогичного поведения под Linux?
Я пробовал posix_spawn. Он не блокирует, возвращает pid запущенного процесса, по которому можно ждать его завершения, но не позволяет получить код возврата.
Std::system позволяет получить код возврата, но не выдает никакого идентификатора созданного процесса, поскольку блокирует вызывающий поток. И вывод запущенной на исполнение команды идет в терминал основного процесса.
Я попробовал скомбинировать std::system с std::async, чтобы вместо блокировки основного потока блокировался дочерний.
std::future<int> res = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]() {
    return std::system(commandLine.c_str());
    });

Это позволяет асинхронно ждать завершения процесса и получить его код возврата, но вывод сообщений все равно пойдет в терминал родительского процесса, а не в отдельный терминал.
Самое близкое, что я нашел, это boost:process:child. Есть хэндл, есть возможность асинхронно ждать завершения и получить код возврата, но вывод идет не туда, куда хотелось бы. Правда, есть возможность полностью перенаправить поток вывода в файл или другой поток, но это не совсем то, что нужно.
return boost::process::child(exeName, boost::process::std_out > "output.txt", boost::process::start_dir = workDir);

Можно вообще как-то добиться желаемого поведения?

Можно явно запустить процесс консоли, например gnome-terminal, и передать исполняемую команду в аргументах. Хотя выяснение, какой этот исполняемый файл и как его запускать на конкретной системе - тот еще квест.

@user7860670 и получить ошибку Can't open display, ага)

@andreymal ¿Почему обязательно эту ошибку?

@user7860670 А как в таком случае получить из терминала код возврата исполняемой команды? Я так понимаю, будет возвращен код успешного завершения работы терминала, а не исполняемой команды.

Вполне вероятно, что терминал возвращает код завершения запущенной программы в качестве своего кода завершения.

Обычно gnome-terminal (и подобные ему современные эмуляторы (но не старый xterm)) сначала делают дочерний процесс, создающий окно в котором запускают (если вы использовали правильные флаги и аргументы) нужную вам команду. Естественно, что таким образом получить ее код возврата (наверняка вам интересен именно он) не удастся. Т.е. вам предстоит некая экспедиция по доставке этого кода (например, через файл) от запускаемой в таком эмуляторе терминала обертке, которая будет исполнять интересующую вас команду хоть через system (хотя, imho, это не лучший вариант (но проще всего реализуемый))
